# How to serialize a Wagtail Orderable model?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I came across a challenge which I also intent to blog about. I found a solution but, since I'm going to write about it, I wonder if there is a **better way to serialize an Orderable model**.

Context: My `LessonPage(Page)` model has a `LessonPageDocuments(Orderable)` model that will allow users to add multiple documents to a particular LessonPage:

```py
class LessonPageDocuments(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(LessonPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                       related_name='documents')
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocs.Document', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    panels = [
        DocumentChooserPanel('document'),
    ]
```

Now, due to this projects needs and business requirements, we're creating a custom REST API instead of using Wagtail's API.

And the way I found to serialize the `documents` field was the following:

```py
class LessonDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = RichTextSerializer()
    documents = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        video_url = ret['video_url']
        ret['video_url'] = get_embed(video_url).html if video_url else ''
        return ret
    def get_documents(self, lesson):
        """Return serialized document fields and file URL"""
        request = self.context.get('request')
        doc_list = []
        for doc_cluster in lesson.documents.all():
            doc_list.append({
                "url": request.build_absolute_uri(doc_cluster.document.file.url),
                "title": doc_cluster.document.title,
                "id": doc_cluster.document.pk,
            })
        return doc_list
    class Meta:
        model = LessonPage
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'slug', 'description',
                  'video_url', 'content', 'documents']
```

Is there a better approach to serialize this field?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way (that I know of) to do it better is to make it reusable:

`wagtail_api/serializers.py`

```
from wagtail.documents.api.v2.serializers import DocumentDownloadUrlField
from wagtail.documents.models import Document

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    _detail_url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='api:wagtail:documents:detail')
    download_url = DocumentDownloadUrlField()

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = (
            '_detail_url',
            'id', 'title', 'download_url',
        )
```

`my_app/serializers.py`

```
class SomePageDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    description = RichTextAPIField()
    document = DocumentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = SomePage
        fields = ('description', 'document')
```

There is also probably a way to overwrite wagtails DocumentSerializer
`from ee_wagtail.apps.wagtail_api.serializers`